# PHP, Ajax form validation

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have this form and I'm trying to validate the user input using PHP. If the input boxes are blank then print all the error messages in the #debug div.  This is the JSON array I want to display at the bottom of the page for debugging purposes.

```
<h2>Form Validation with AJAX,JQuery,JSON and PHP</h2>
          <div class="form-container">    
              <span id="ajax-message"></span>


              <form id="ajax-form" onsubmit="return false;">
                  <p class="legend">All fields marked with an asterisk are required.</p>

                  <fieldset>
                      <legend>User Details</legend>
                      <div>
                        <label for="uname">Username <em>*</em></label> 
                        <input id="uname" type="text" name="uname" value=""  />
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <label for="email">Email Address <em>*</em></label> 
                        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" />
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <label for="fname" class="error">First Name <em>*</em></label> 
                        <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" value="" size="50" class="error"/>
                        <p class='note'>This is where the error message should go </p> 
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <label for="lname">Last Name <em>*</em></label> 
                        <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname" value="" size="50" />
                      </div>
                  </fieldset>

                  <div class="buttonrow">
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit This Form via AJAX" class="button" />  
                      <input type="button" value="Start Again" class="button" />
                      <a href="ajaxformval.html">Refresh this Page</a>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div> 
      <h3>JSON Array</h3>
      <pre id='debug'></pre>
```

I've sent the form info in an array using ajax like so:

```
      $.post(
            'ajaxformval_post.php', 
            variableToSend,
            function(data){
                alert(data['post']['uname']);
                $("#debug").html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
                },
            "json"
          );
```

and In the php part, I am printing the form values that were passed but I also want to print the error messages if errors occurred all in one array. for example: 
    `{
       "post":{
          "uname":"anyNameUserEnters",
          "email":"Any Email", 
          "lname":"A last name", 
          "fname":"first name"},
        "postVarErrorMsgs":{
           "uname":"Please enter a username",
           "email":"required",
           "lname":"reqiured",
           "fname":"required"
    }`
can anyone please help me?

```
if(!isset($_POST['uname']) || strlen(trim($_POST['uname'])) == 0){
    $json['postVarErrorMsg']['uname']=='Please enter your name.';
}
if(!isset($_POST['email']) || strlen(trim($_POST['email'])) == 0){
    $json['postVarErrorMsg']['email']=='An email address is required.';
}
if(!isset($_POST['lname']) || strlen(trim($_POST['lname'])) == 0){
    $json['postVarErrorMsg']['lname']=='Your last name must be entered too.';
}
if(!isset($_POST['fname']) || strlen(trim($_POST['fname'])) == 0){
    $json['postVarErrorMsg']['fname']=='We very much require your first name.';
}



$json = array(
        'post' =>array(
            'uname' =>$_POST['uname'],
            'email' =>$_POST['email'],
            'lname' =>$_POST['lname'],
            'fname' =>$_POST['fname']
            ),

        //print existing error messages

);
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you override the whole array when you do this. Since you redeclared the `$json` array.

```
$json = array(
    'post' =>array(
        'uname' =>$_POST['uname'],
        'email' =>$_POST['email'],
        'lname' =>$_POST['lname'],
        'fname' =>$_POST['fname']
        ),
```

so basically, you need to restructure how you inserted data to your array.

```
$json['post'] = array(
        'uname' =>$_POST['uname'],
        'email' =>$_POST['email'],
        'lname' =>$_POST['lname'],
        'fname' =>$_POST['fname']
        );
```

This means, you are adding another top-level key with `post` as its key name. The same level with `postVarErrorMsg`.

Don't do something like this:

```
$json = array(some data);
```

because this means you are redeclaring your array and removing all the previous data that you stored in it.

A much easier implementation is using `array_merge` function:

```
$post_data = array(some data);
$error_data = array(some error data);
$json = array_merge($post_data, $error_data);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did that and it works now, and I also realized that I was assigning values using "==" in the error array which was also causing the problem.